# Django gives Bad Request (400) when DEBUG = False

Tags: python, django

I am new to django-1.6. When I run the django server with `DEBUG = True`, it's running perfectly. But when I change `DEBUG` to `False` in the settings file, then the server stopped and it gives the following error on the command prompt:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

After I changed `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `["http://127.0.0.1:8000",]`, in the browser I get the error:

```
Bad Request (400)
```

Is it possible to run Django without debug mode?

Comment: One thing to remember: do not add 'http' or 'https' in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Answer (score 496, accepted):

The [`ALLOWED_HOSTS` list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) should contain fully qualified *host names*, **not** urls. Leave out the port and the protocol. If you are using `127.0.0.1`, I would add `localhost` to the list too:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

You could also use `*` to match *any* host:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Values in this list can be fully qualified names (e.g. `'www.example.com'`), in which case they will be matched **against the request’s `Host` header** exactly (case-insensitive, **not including port**). A value beginning with a period can be used as a subdomain wildcard: `'.example.com'` will match `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and any other subdomain of `example.com`. A value of `'*'` will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the `Host` header (perhaps in a middleware; if so this middleware must be listed first in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`).

*Bold emphasis mine*.

The status 400 response you get is due to a [`SuspiciousOperation` exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation) being raised when your host header doesn't match any values in that list.

Comment: Thanks it works, But when I set False, one issue comes, for all the static files is shown as 404. I could not understand why it gives not found

Comment: @MegaBytes: sorry, I don't know what that might be.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do it, becasue my project is going on production.

Comment: Again, I have no idea even what you are setting to `False`. Perhaps you could post a new question?

Comment: @MegaBytes When DEBUG is False, all static file are served from the STATIC_ROOT, so probally a `./manage.py collectstatic` will do.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and none of the answers resolved my problem. For resolving situations like this, it's best to enable logging by adding the following config to `settings.py` temporarily.

```
LOGGING = {
   'version': 1,
   'disable_existing_loggers': False,
   'handlers': {
      'file': {
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
         'filename': '/tmp/debug.log',
      },
   },
   'loggers': {
      'django': {
         'handlers': ['file'],
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'propagate': True,
      },
   },
}
```

When you see the issue, it's easier to handle than by blind debugging.

My issue was:

**Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'pt_web:8000'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.**

I resolved it by adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to the Nginx config file and enabling port forwarding with `USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = True` in the `settings.py` (it's because in my case I was listening to requests on Nginx port `8080` and passing to `guni` on port `8000`).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For my case in prod, after I add the LOGGING=..., then I see the error  "ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for...css". Then I use "python manager.py collectstatic" as mentioned above by @Blackeagle52, the 500 error (can also be 400 error in my local dev) is solved.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/app-log/django.log'. `

Comment: I changed the path to `django.log` to try to get around the missing file error and there's a log file created now but it's empty.

Comment: I had the exact same "RFC 1034/1035" error, but it was because of an underscore in my url. Check this before trying to modify nginx or Django confs.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I got this error by not setting [`USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST) to true.  From the docs:

> This should only be enabled if a proxy which sets this header is in use.

My hosting service [wrote](https://wiki.uberspace.de/cool:django#django-projekt_anlegen_und_konfigurieren) explicitly in their documentation that this setting *must* be used, and I get this 400 error if I forget it.

Comment: Is this necessary if ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']?

Comment: I think ALLOWED_HOSTS blocks the entire host.  USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST only determines if an HTTP header is used.

Answer (score 4):

in the settings.py of your project, check line 28, where is the Allows Host

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP', 'servidor', ]
```

you must put the IP and the server you use, level local or web
settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.ejemplo.com']
```

or

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` and to solve the problem with the static images you have to change the virtual paths in the environment configuration like this:

**Virtual Path** 
                **Directory**
/static/                          /opt/python/current/app/yourpj/static/
/media/                        /opt/python/current/app/Nuevo/media/

I hope it helps you.

PD: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

With `DEBUG = False` in you settings file, you also need ALLOWED_HOST list set up.
Try including `ALLOWED_HOST = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.yourdomain.com']`

Otherwise you might receive a Bad Request(400) error from django.

Answer (score 2):

For me as I have already xampp on 127.0.0.1 and django on 127.0.1.1
and i kept trying adding hosts

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.yourdomain.com', '*', '127.0.1.1']
```

and i got the same error or (400) bad request
[image]

so I change the url to 127.0.1.1:(the used port)/project
and voila !

you have to check what is your virtual network address, for me as i use bitnami django stack 2.2.3-1 on Linux i can check which port django is using.
if you have an error ( 400 bad request ) then i guess django on different virtual network ..
good luck 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to stop the apache server first.

(f.e. `sudo systemctl stop httpd.service` / `sudo systemctl disable httpd.service`).

That solved my problem besides editing the '`settings.py`' file

to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['se.rv.er.ip', 'www.example.com']`

Answer (score 0):

try `manage.py collectstatic`.
I was missing a static file after an update, hence the bad request.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other reasons I know (less frequent but still) that can cause  400 bad request:

1. Nginx Doesn’t Pass $Host To Your Application
2. Host Name Has Underscores

I outlined these examples [here](https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/how-to-fix-bad-request-400-in-django/)

Answer (score -3):

Try to run your server with the `--insecure` flag, just like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```