# Django Debug = False returns bad request even Allowed_Host = ['localhost','127.0.0.1'] is configured

Tags: django

I get Bad Request (400) on my localhost when my DEBUG = False. Even I configured ALLOWED_HOSTS. I have been searching all over stackoverflow but still can't find the source of the problems.

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: It should work with just `localhost`. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django==1.10.5

Comment: I'm thinking the 400 is coming from something else and isn't related to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, because your config is right. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false), maybe it helps

Comment: That's what I thought too but it is clear that the bad request only appears when the DEBUG = False. I checked on that link but they don't answer my issue.

Comment: Try making a new, fresh project and just change those two configs and see if it works. That rules out any issues from your python or django installs. If that doesn't work, see if any middlewares you've installed are causing the problem. Commenting out things in your config is a surprisingly effective way to narrowing down a problem like this.

Comment: As an option, try writing your own 400 handler and get the actual error manually: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#handler400

Comment: I started a new project and the result is the same except when I put 127.0.0.1, together with localhost, in the ALLOWED_HOSTS: then I got: Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server. I am thinking this error is caused by an middleware just like you suggested user2896976. Now I just need to figure an effective way to isolate that middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'*'` to the list just in case and see if that helps.

Comment: I did but that doesn't help.