# Use Django REST framework serializer to save JSON requests to database

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm absolutely new to Django and for some reason, I had to jump right to Django REST framework.
I want to save JSON objects sent as POST requests in my database.
The JSON object looks like this:

```
[{
    "title": "Bitcoin Price Likely to Reach $50K Soon According to This Indicator",
    "description": "",
    "date": "2021-02-09T09:08:58Z",
    "link": "https://cryptopotato.com/bitcoin-price-likely-to-reach-50k-soon-according-to-this-indicator/",
    "keywords": [{
        "name": "bitcoin"
    }],
    "source": "https://cryptocompare.com"
},
{
    "title": "Post-Tesla News FOMO Helps Bitcoin Price to Surge Above $48,000",
    "description": "",
    "date": "2021-02-09T09:08:58Z",
    "link": "https://www.cryptoglobe.com/latest/2021/02/post-tesla-news-fomo-helps-bitcoin-price-to-surge-above-48000/",
    "keywords": [{
        "name": "bitcoin"
    }],
    "source": "https://cryptocompare.com"
}]
```

I created my models like this:

```
class Keywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    link = models.URLField()
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "News"
        # ordering = "-date"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers:

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Keywords
        fields = ["name"]


class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keywords = KeywordSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ["title", "description", "date", "link", "keywords", "source"]
```

and finally my view:

```
class NewsView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):    
        news_serializer = NewsSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)

        try:
            if news_serializer.is_valid():
                news_serializer.save()
                return Response("Created successfully", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return Response("Error, Don't know what", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Normally i try to not to post vague and general questions, but in this one, i've got absolutely no idea how to debug and find the problem here. The only thing that i get from terminal is

```
Bad Request: /news/
```

could you please point out the problem, and also give a solution on how to fix it?

Comment: try to print the exception **print(e.args)**

Comment: thanks, did so! `print(e.args)` results in `('keywords',)` in terminal! do you have any idea what's wrong with keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me help try to help you out with this problem.

In current state, the solution will be to override the `create` method of the `NewsSerializer` to create the news and keyword instances.

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  ...
  def create(self, validated_data):
    keywords = validated_data.pop("keywords", None)

    news, _ = News.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
   
    if news:
       for keyword in keywords:
           keyword, _ = Keywords.objects.get_or_create(**keyword)
           news.keywords.add(key)
    return news
```

Also I would update the post method of view as follow:

```
...
def post(self, request):
   for news in request.data:
       serializer = NewsSerializer(news)
       serializer.save(raise_exception=True)
return Response("Created successfully", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, there might be a validation error.

**description** is required in the model and you are passing empty. ***>> "description": "",***

```
      try:
            if news_serializer.is_valid():
                news_serializer.save()
                return Response("Created successfully", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
           else: 
              print(news_serializer.errors)
              return Response('Invalid data') # whatever you want
```

Read https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework

Comment: Fixed this one also, but still, all I get is `Bad Request: /news/` error. can't Django show a more precise and informative error? if so, how can I enable that? Thank you very much.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false