# Django Bad Request (400) Debug=False

Tags: django

I'm trying to publish my site, i configured all settings (nginx & gunicorn)

This settings works well

```
DEBUG=True
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['localhost','127.0.0.1','domain.com','www.domain.com']
```

However, when i edit the DEBUG=True to False

```
DEBUG=False
```

i got this error on browser `Bad Request (400)`

i also tried these setttings

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['*']
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['domain.com','www.domain.com']
```

(before posting this question i checked this answer [Django gives Bad Request (400) when DEBUG = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false) )

Answer (score 0):

did you try restarting gunicorn?: `PID=$(systemctl show --value -p MainPID gunicorn.service) && kill -HUP $PID`

Comment: yes i tried, both your answer and these commands `sudo systemctl stop gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.service`

Comment: Do you still have the .sock file in the project folder?, sometimes it gets deleted when applying changes to the project configuration. I used to have this problem when deploying in a digital ocean droplet